# Django REST Framework update foreign key field on PUT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.x` and `Django REST Framework`

My **models.py** file contents

```
class ModeOfPayment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField()

class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    mode_of_payment = models.ForeignKey(
        ModeOfPayment,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        null=True
    )
```

and **serializers.py**

```
class ModeOfPaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModeOfPayment
        fields = ('id', 'title')


class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mode_of_payment = ModeOfPaymentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AmountGiven
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 'contact', 'amount', 'mode_of_payment', 
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        mode_of_payment = validated_data.pop('mode_of_payment')
        instance.mode_of_payment_id = mode_of_payment.id
        return instance
```

and **views.py**

```
class AmountGivenViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AmountGivenSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)
    filter_fields = ('contact__id',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = AmountGiven.objects.filter(
            contact__user=self.request.user
        )

        return queryset
```

But when I post data using `postman` with **PUT** method to update the existing record

[image]

It still says

```
{
    "mode_of_payment": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

> Edit 2: Response after Daniel answer

```
{
    "id": "326218dc-66ab-4c01-95dc-ce85f226012d",
    "contact": {
        "id": "b1b87766-86c5-4029-aa7f-887f436d6a6e",
        "first_name": "Prince",
        "last_name": "Raj",
        "user": 3
    },
    "amount": 3000,
    "mode_of_payment": "0cd51796-a423-4b75-a0b5-80c03f7b1e65",
}
```

Comment: Well you provide for the `mode_of_payment`, the `title`, not an identifier.

Comment: I already have `mode_of_payment` records added and want to update to one that already exists in the `mode_of_payments` table. That's why passing identifier.

Comment: yes but is this the identifier? Normally an identifier is a numerical value, not an GUID, etc.

Comment: yes, it's `UUID` field. Updated question with `id` field in **models.py**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told AmountSerializer to accept a nested dict representing a ModeOfPayment instance, by setting the `mode_of_payment` field to ModeOfPaymentSerializer. But that's not what you're sending; you're sending the ID of the ModeOfPayment.

<strike>You should remove that line in AmountGivenSerializer.</strike>

**Edit**

I was wrong, you need to declare the field explicitly as a PrimaryKeyRelatedField:

```
class AmountGivenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mode_of_payment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModeOfPayment.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Now it will accept a UUID in the data.

Comment: I tried that too by removing `mode_of_payment = ModeOfPaymentSerializer()` but then it started giving **KeyError** at line `mode_of_payment = validated_data.pop('mode_of_payment')`

Comment: I printed `validated_data` before the error line and noticed that it does not have `mode_of_payment` field in it. `{'amount': 3000.0}`

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the UUID of an existing ModeOfPayment instance? If it doesn't correspond to one that exists in the database, it won't be included in validated_data.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I copied the `uuid` after listing all the payment modes.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, It works but in response, it is not including details of `mode_of_payment` instead only `id` of the mode of payment. but having details up to depth 1 for contact field. See **Edit 2` for the response.